# PrimeNg MenuItem still clickable when disabled

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNg MenuItems for navigation links on my website and I conditionally set the disabled property to true.
The links appear to be disabled but they still work when you click.

The PrimeNg [MenuItem documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/menu) has no explanation for this.

The workaround I made was to also set the routerLink to false as seen in the second menuItem in the image below.

[image]

I'd like to know if there's a reason/explanation for this behavior or if there's a cleaner solution to it.